# How to handle C-Files in Xcode 11 package manager?

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, package-managers

I have a C-function, which I call in a Swift wrapper function.
Now, I want to create a Swift-package with this Swift wrapper function.
However, I am doing something wrong.

Here is the C-function which adds 2 double values.

```
//  addDoubles.c
#include <math.h>
#include "addDoubles.h"

double addDoubleWithC(double val1, double val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
}
```

Here is the Swift file with a wrapping function:

```
//  WrappedCFunctions.swift
import Foundation
public struct WrappedCFunctions {    
public static func addDoubles(val1:Double, val2:Double) -> Double{
    let resulFromCFunction = addDoubleWithC(val1, val2)
return resulFromCFunction
}
}
```

In the viewController I am using this function:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let val1 = 1.11
    let val2 = 2.22
    let result = WrappedCFunctions.addDoubles(val1: val1, val2: val2) 
    let txt = String(val1) + " + " + String(val2) + " = " + String(result)
    textLabel.text = txt
}
}
```

The project structure is the following:

[image]

This app works correctly, as expected.

In the next step I created with File-> New-> Swift Packe a package with name Math.
Then I moved the file WrappedCFunctions.swift from the AddDoubles Folder into the CMath/Source/CMath folder of the package. In the next step I included the package into the project. This leads to the following structure:

[image]

Last but not least I added an Import CMath statement in ViewController.swift and built the project.

However, the package is not recognised.

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your `Package.swift` file it is impossible to know if you package is setup correctly. Looking at the pictures you did post the best guess I have is that it is not configured properly.

The reason I am guessing this is that you only have 1 directory in your `Sources/` when you will need 2 targets (usually with SwiftPM you have 1 directory per target and I don't see any .c files in the package). The C code will need to be a target that the Swift target depends on. Then you have a product that depends on the Swift target. That product is what you will link and import in Xcode.

If you look at [this](https://github.com/bscothern/Once) repo I have, I use both C and Swift so you can see how I have setup the `Package.swift` to build the 2 targets.